# Gerund vs infinitive

Tags: verbs, infinitive, gerund

I'm currently reading *Ad Alpes* and came across the following sentence:

**"Nonne sunt qui putent earum volatu res futuras portendi?"**

Now, as I understand it the meaning of this sentence is: **"are there not those who think/believe/consider that by their [birds'] flight the future is foretold?"**

So, my beginner's question is: why does the verb take the gerund form and not the infinitive? Am I mistranslating the way in which foretold is being used?

Comment: *portendi* is infinitive. So either the question got reversed or you have your answer.

Comment: @d_e Aha! So it is - passive infinitive. I just saw the '-di' and assumed a genitive gerund. Thanks so much.

Comment: yeah. That's confusing indeed. the gerundive would be *portendendi*

Comment: @d_e I recommend you turn your comment into an answer. Nice work.